# getStaticProps in HOC not working in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an HOC and a getStaticProps function for that HOC like this below:

```
const WrappedPage = () => {
    const WithLocale = ({ locale, ...pageProps }) => {
        if (!locale) {
            return <Error statusCode={404} />
        }
        return (
            <LocaleProvider lang={locale}>
                <WrappedPage {...pageProps} />
            </LocaleProvider>
        )
    }

    return WithLocale
}

export default WrappedPage

export const getStaticProps = async ctx => {
    let pageProps = {}
    if (WrappedPage.getStaticProps) {
        pageProps = await WrappedPage.getStaticProps(ctx)
    }
    if (typeof ctx.query.lang !== 'string' || !isLocale(ctx.query.lang)) {
        return { ...pageProps, locale: undefined }
    }
    return { ...pageProps, locale: ctx.query.lang }
}
```

For some reason, the getStaticProps function for the HOC here isn't working. If I try to console log the `ctx` inside the function, it doesn't output anything.

Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong here would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you are using HOC in the right way, ref (https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

in HOC, you pass a component in and the HOC provides additional props and/or rendered components:

```
const WithLocale = (Component, locale, ...otherProps) => {
    if (!locale) {
        return <Error statusCode={404} />
    }
    return (
        <LocaleProvider lang={locale}>
            <Component {...otherProps} />
        </LocaleProvider>
    )
}

const WrappedPage = ({prop1, prop2}) => <h1>{prop1 + ' ' + prop2}</h1>

export default withLocale(WrappedPage, locale, prop1, prop2 etc)
```